# SendMessage/SC_MONITORPOWER won't turn monitor OFF

Tags: c#, sendmessage

When calling this command in C#:

```
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)SC_MONITORPOWER, (IntPtr)2);
```

It used to turn the screen off.
But since I switched to Windows 10, coming from Windows 7, the screen turns black for a second (doesn't go to sleep, just like showing a black image) and then the Windows desktop comes up again.

Did Microsoft change something regard this functionality? If so, I couldn't find anything on the web.

Regards,
Simon